# Why the boundary of $(a,b]$ is $\{ a,b \}$?

Tags: general-topology

I found an example in Nakahara's Ex.2.10, and what makes me confusing from that is,

**"For a usual topology with $\mathbb{R}$, the sets $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b)$, $[a,b]$ have the same boundary."**

I think the largest open subset(=interior) of them is $(a,b)$ and with the definition of boundary(=complement of interior), I guess the boundaries of the above sets are

$\{b\}$, $\{a\}$, $\emptyset$, $\{a,b\}$ respectively.

Am I right or wrong?
Can anyone tell the truth?!

Thank you!

Comment: The boundary is the complement of the interior in the closure of the set.

Answer (score 3):

You have found the interior correctly but the boundary of  a set is not the set minus the interior. It is the closure of the set minus the interior.

Comment: Some texts call $ A \setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$ the "frontier" of $A$, or Fr($A$).

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  Oh, then the boundary of a set $A$ actually doesn't have to be a part of the $A$. It's a bit weird for my intuition...Anyway! Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Wow, that concept is more intuitive for me! Thank you!

Comment: @김성준 I fact the boundary of the set of all rational numbers is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: @김성준 In the book you are reading they are using the standard definition of boundary which is the one I gave, Whether it is intutive to you or not that is the usual definition of boundary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The problem was a typo in the definition of the boundary in the book, which says $b(A) = A - \text{interior}(A)$, not $b(A) = \text{closure}(A) - \text{interior}(A)$